# multer and post processing files?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am using multer in my node.js app, though I am trying to see how I should go about finding where multer placed the file in my post function, so that I can do post procesing on it. What is the right way? Currently I have this:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer()


var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
     callback(null, './public/uploads/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});

var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'myfile', maxCount: 1 }]);

app.post('/profile', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) {
   var destination, filename;
   storage.getDestination(req, req.files.myfile[0], function(param1, dest) { destination = dest; })
   storage.getFilename(req, req.files.myfile[0], function(param1, fn) { filename = fn; })
   var path = destination + '/' + filename;
})
```

I had looked in the `req.files.myfile[0]` entry to see if the destination path was provided, but that does not appear to be the case:

```
{ fieldname: 'myfile',
  originalname: 'mytextfile.txt',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'text/plain' }
```

I want to be sure that whatever approach I used is compatible with the expectations of the API.

Comment: Is `req.files.myfile` actually set to an array or is it undefined? If it is set, what does `req.files.myfile` contain?

Comment: Have updated question to reflect what I see

Comment: This is odd, I now see filename, path, and destination as part of the result. Other than doing a new npm install, I am not sure what else I might have changed here?

Comment: maybe try setting the destination folder like this?
var upload = multer({  dest: './uploads/'  });

Answer (score 0):

Using the `multer` functions with no field name specified results in no files being saved (it saves only non-file fields in that case). If you want to accept file fields, you have to pass the string name of the field.

Comment: In making a simplified example of my issue I oversimplified it. Have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

multer providing uploaded file details in res object

```
router.post('/file_upload', upload.single('photo'), function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.file) 
    res.status(204).end()
});
```

[image]

ref: - 
http://wiki.workassis.com/nodejs-express-get-post-multipart-request-handling-example/